# Proving that $\alpha\gamma$ and $\beta\gamma$ have no gcd where $\alpha=3$ , $\beta=(1+2\sqrt{-5})$ and $\gamma=7(1+2\sqrt{-5})$in ring $Z[√(-5)]$

Tags: abstract-algebra, ring-theory, gcd-and-lcm

I have the following question before me :

$\alpha=3$ and $\beta=1+2\sqrt{-5}$ are two elements of ring $R=Z[\sqrt{-5}]$.
$\gamma=7(1+2\sqrt{-5})$ is another element of this ring.

I have to prove that elements $\alpha\gamma$ and $\beta\gamma$ have no gcd in $R$.

In this case, it turns out that $\alpha$ and $\beta$ are relatively prime.
This exact question has been asked before as well. But that was way back in $2013$. And my query on that page went unanswered. That's why I have asked a new question here.

One of the comments on that page says that potential candidates for gcd of $\alpha\gamma$ and $\beta\gamma$ are $1$,$-1$ (units in $R$ ),$7$ and $(1+2\sqrt{-5})$.

I could not quite understand why $\gamma$ is not a potential candidate for gcd here as $\gamma$ divides both $\alpha\gamma$ and $\beta\gamma$

Infact $\gamma$ is divisible by all the common factors of $\alpha\gamma$ and $\beta\gamma$. Then why is $\gamma$ not regarded as gcd here?

Please help me out regarding this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are right that $\gamma=7(1+2\sqrt{-5})$ is a common divisor. If it were **the greatest common divisor** then any other common divisor $\delta$ would have to divide it, $\delta\mid \gamma$. Now consider the element $\delta=(1+2\sqrt{-5})^2$.

This is a common divisor of $\gamma\alpha$ and $\gamma\beta$, as

- $\gamma\alpha=3\cdot 7(1+2\sqrt{-5})=(1-2\sqrt{-5})(1+\sqrt{-5})^2$
- $\gamma\beta=7\cdot (1+2\sqrt{-5})^2$

Now, lets check if $\delta\mid\gamma$ or $\gamma\mid\delta$, that is if one divides the other. We have:

- $\frac{(1+2\sqrt{-5})^2}{7(1+2\sqrt{-5})}=\frac{1+2\sqrt{-5}}{7}\not\in\Bbb Z[\sqrt{-5}]$
- $\frac{7(1+2\sqrt{-5})}{(1+2\sqrt{-5})^2}=\frac{1-2\sqrt{-5}}{3}\not\in\Bbb Z[\sqrt{-5}]$

Also, $\gamma,\delta$ are not associated, as $N(\gamma)\neq N(\delta)$.

Comment: What is the way to go about this problem if such question appears in an exam?

Comment: @HARVEERRAWAT I'm not sure. What I did was to try different factorizations of $\gamma\alpha$, and see if I could get new factors that also appeared in $\gamma\beta$. I noticed that $21=a^2+5b^2$ had a solution, that is, $N(1\pm 2\sqrt{-5})=21$. From there I could write $21=(2+\sqrt{-5})(2-\sqrt{-5})$. Also $(2+\sqrt{-5})(2-\sqrt{-5})=3\cdot 7$ are two different factorizations of $21$ into irreducibles.